# Using same variables in JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables, html-table

I am trying to use my variables I created in the JavaScript  part of my document outside of named document. Like this:

```
<script>
var Number = 1;
var Number2 = 2;
var Result = Number 1 + 2;
</script>

<p> Result </p>
```

To be more precise I would like to use the variable I created in the Script in an table. Like this:

```
<table class="tabelle">
  <tr>
    <td><script> Result </script></td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried it by marking a new script area in my table, but this doesn't seem to work. I hope you can get the basic concept of my problem.

Further: I thought I might create some global variables in HTML AND JavaScript but I wouldn't know how.

Comment: One way is to use document.write(Result). There are other ways as well though

Comment: This is covered in almost any intro to web programming. The simplest way is to use `element.textContent = Result;` to place the result in a particular element.

Comment: Number is a built-in Javascript type and you don't want to be replacing it

Answer (score 0):

Id' recommend something like this. You can use the innerHTML method to set the HTML of any selected element. I gave the cell an id to more easily identify what was being targeted.

```html
<body>

<table class="tabelle">
  <tr>
    <td id='result-cell'></td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
var num1 = 1;
var num2 = 2;
var result = num1 + num2;
document.getElementById('result-cell').innerHTML = '<p>' + result + '</p>';
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: This script works basically perfect, but in my case the whole funktion stops working when adding the line: `code`document.getElementById('result-cell').innerHTML = '<p>' + result + '</p>'; to the code. There could be a connection with the fact that my variabe "result" is a number that changes while the Script is loaded.

Comment: It should work if you remember to give the cell the id, make sure that the result var your calling has the same name as what is defined, and lastly make sure to remove the script tags from inside the td. You won't need them to update. It would be better do add an event handler for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML doesn't recognize `Result` as a variable! The DOM is going to be rendered assuming `Result` is just text.

There's two ways you can get your view to render that variable:

1. In the  section, include instructions for Javascript to go in and modify the DOM. That'll look something like:

`...(your code)...
 resultElement = document.querySelector('p.result');
 resultElement.innerHTML = result;`

Where the selector is where you want to write your result value. Your code gives `result` a value. These next lines go in and write that value to the DOM by inserting it as text to whichever DOM element you like.

2. Use a templating engine, like [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/). This approach is more complicated to set up, but would allow you to very naturally write your variables into a template using brackets:

Script: `var result = 'Howdy!'`

Template: `<p> {{result}} </p>`

For a small project, the first approach is probably the most appropriate.